# Mutt won't let me send emails because "Sasl authentication failed"

Tags: email, settings, authentication, mutt, sasl

I've installed all the required packages for mutt to send emails smtp.

```
mutt -v
Mutt 1.13.2 (2019-12-18)
Copyright (C) 1996-2016 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: Linux 5.8.0-38-generic (x86_64)
ncurses: ncurses 6.2.20200212 (compiled with 6.2)
libidn: 1.33 (compiled with 1.33)
hcache backend: tokyocabinet 1.4.48

Compiler:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-HskZEa/gcc-9-9.3.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 

Configure options: '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--prefix=/usr' '--includedir=\${prefix}/include' '--mandir=\${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=\${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--disable-silent-rules' '--libdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=\${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--with-mailpath=/var/mail' '--enable-compressed' '--enable-debug' '--enable-fcntl' '--enable-hcache' '--enable-gpgme' '--enable-imap' '--enable-smtp' '--enable-pop' '--enable-sidebar' '--enable-nntp' '--enable-dotlock' '--disable-fmemopen' '--with-curses' '--with-gnutls' '--with-gss' '--with-idn' '--with-mixmaster' '--with-sasl' '--without-gdbm' '--without-bdb' '--without-qdbm' '--with-tokyocabinet' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mutt-j2y3Jo/mutt-1.13.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' 'CPPFLAGS=-Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'

Compilation CFLAGS: -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/mutt-j2y3Jo/mutt-1.13.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security

Compile options:
-DOMAIN
+DEBUG
-HOMESPOOL  +USE_SETGID  +USE_DOTLOCK  +DL_STANDALONE  +USE_FCNTL  -USE_FLOCK   
+USE_POP  +USE_IMAP  +USE_SMTP  
-USE_SSL_OPENSSL  +USE_SSL_GNUTLS  +USE_SASL  +USE_GSS  +HAVE_GETADDRINFO  
+HAVE_REGCOMP  -USE_GNU_REGEX  
+HAVE_COLOR  +HAVE_START_COLOR  +HAVE_TYPEAHEAD  +HAVE_BKGDSET  
+HAVE_CURS_SET  +HAVE_META  +HAVE_RESIZETERM  +HAVE_FUTIMENS  
+CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_PGP  +CRYPT_BACKEND_CLASSIC_SMIME  +CRYPT_BACKEND_GPGME  
-EXACT_ADDRESS  -SUN_ATTACHMENT  
+ENABLE_NLS  -LOCALES_HACK  +HAVE_WC_FUNCS  +HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET  +HAVE_LANGINFO_YESEXPR  
+HAVE_ICONV  -ICONV_NONTRANS  +HAVE_LIBIDN  -HAVE_LIBIDN2  +HAVE_GETSID  +USE_HCACHE  
+USE_SIDEBAR  +USE_COMPRESSED  +USE_INOTIFY  
-ISPELL
SENDMAIL="/usr/sbin/sendmail"
MAILPATH="/var/mail"
PKGDATADIR="/usr/share/mutt"
SYSCONFDIR="/etc"
EXECSHELL="/bin/sh"
MIXMASTER="mixmaster"

To contact the developers, please mail to <mutt-dev@mutt.org>.
To report a bug, please contact the Mutt maintainers via gitlab:
    https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/issues
```

`.muttrc`:

```
set from = "user@domain.com"
set realname = "Firstname Lastname"

set smtp_url = "smtps://user@domain.com@smtp.domain.com:465/"
set smtp_pass = "password"
set imap_user = "user@domain.com"
set imap_pass = "password"

set folder = "imaps://imap.domain.com:993"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set editor = "nano"
```

Any help with troubleshooting from here?

Comment: SASL Authentication Failed means you attempted to authenticate and the authentication failed, you sure your passwords and such are accurate?

Comment: yes, I'm 100% sure